# Dynamic color change

Tags: web, colors

I'm designing a website for a client. He builds storage units. He wants customers to select a color option and it change the color of the cabin image. I have no idea how to do this. Any tips?

Comment: please explain your problem in detail, what language, framework are you working in?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: I am using basic HTML and Css. Sherwin Willams has a page that you pick a paint color and the color of the house on the page changes...that's what I'm essentially trying to do.